# React Native parent component to screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

I would like to have a parent component wrapping the screens so I can pass global styles to those components like instead of repeating same global styles in each component. However, Navigator doesn't accept View or anything with styles inside it.

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Navigator>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <>
            <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name={'TabsNavigation'} component={BottomTabsNavigator}/>
            <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name={'Home'} component={Home}/>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name={'Login'} component={Login}/>
            <Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name={'Register'} component={Register}/>
          </>
        )}
      </Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

All my components start like this:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles(theme).flex}>
    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
        <View>
            <Text>Content here</Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

So instead I want to make it so all my components start like this:

```
<View>
    <Text>Content here</Text>
</View>
```

I want to move `SafeAreaView` and `ScrollView` to a parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the edit it's much more clear, thanks!  And the answer is very different so I made a new one.

What you want is called an HOC, for Higher-Order Component.  React makes this easy with the `children` prop.  Here's an example based on your code:

```js
const ScreenWrapper = ({ children, theme }) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles(theme).flex}>
      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic">
        {children}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

You'd use this in your screens like this:

```js
  <ScreenWrapper>
    <View>
      <Text>Content here</Text>
    </View>
  </ScreenWrapper>
```

Anything between `<ScreenWrapper>` and `</ScreenWrapper>` is passed to the component under the `children` prop.  This pattern should make it easy to achive what you want.  This is how most of the React built-in components (like View or Text) work.

You can read more about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx

Answer (score 0):

*NB: After the edit, this answer does not fit the question*

---

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to achieve, however, there are many ways to go about using a shared theme.

- React Navigation has built-in theming for its components, using the `theme` prop.  You can read about how to use the theme prop here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/
- You can save and export one or several StyleSheets, and import them wherever you want.  Example:

```js
export const colors = {
  blue: '#02B4F3',
};

export const textStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: colors.blue,
  },
  ...
});

// etc
// and then in your component

import { textStyles } from 'styles';

...
  <Text style={textStyles.header}>Header</Text>
...
```

- You can make functions that return StyleSheets based on the theme.  Example:

```js
export const textStyles = (theme) => StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: theme === 'light' ? colors.blue : colors.yellow,
  },
});
```

- You can use React Context to hold your themes.  There are lots of tutorials for this, like this one (which I haven't tried btw): https://betterprogramming.pub/react-context-api-part-1-dark-theme-3f00666cbacb
- Using a UI library like react-native-paper or Native Base often includes support for theming, although I wouldn't encourage using one only for theming, and in general I do not prefer working with these libraries.

Comment: please see edit :)